# Test and fix Firefox stroke-dashoffset issue without browser version checking

Tags: firefox, browser-detection

Firefox under version 28 has an issue where a path with a stroke-dashoffset property will render differently depending on the stroke-width amount. There is a known fix which is to divide stroke-dashoffset with stroke-width, but applying this across the board will mean other browsers will now display incorrectly.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661812

The quickest solution I can think of is is simply check for browser type and version number, but generally this seems to be regarded as a bad idea. Does anyone know a way to test the result without going down this route?

I have put together a Codepen which allows you to change the width of an animated offset, and a toggle for the fix so you can see for yourselves in different browsers. http://codepen.io/MattyBalaam/full/lGJkc

Comment: It seems even feature detection is no solution in this case, because the lower FF versions do support it but buggy? If so, I guess there is little left than to do a FF version number check. If you would have difficulty with that, I can post a very small and intuitive Javascript that does that specifically for FF.

Comment: The solution I came up with at the time was this, as it is likely to only ever be used for one thing I did not look into expanding it.

`var offSet = 10;
    var widthFix = 1;
    var paths = $('.paths')
    var versionRegex = /Firefox\/([0-9]+)/
    var firefoxVersion = navigator.userAgent.match(versionRegex);
    if ( firefoxVersion !== null && firefoxVersion[1] < 28) {
     widthFix = paths.first().css('stroke-width').replace('px', '');
    } 
    
    paths.css('stroke-dashoffset', offSet/widthFix);`

Comment: If that works, I'd just keep using it. Principally speaking, nothing wrong with a version check in this case.